# rails 4 and mysql storing and accessing json data in an object.

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json, serialization

I have done this with postgresql but I am having trouble getting it implemented with mysql.  I am building a CMS that has the following classes.

```
class Content::Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :route
  has_many :page_elements, :foreign_key => "content_page_id"
  has_many :elements, :foreign_key => "content_element_id", :through => :page_elements
end

class Content::PageElement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :page , :foreign_key => "content_page_id"
  belongs_to :element , :foreign_key => "content_element_id"
  validates_presence_of :content_page_id
  validates_presence_of :content_element_id
  validates_presence_of :position
end

class Content::Element < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
  serialize :data
  validates_presence_of :type
  validates_presence_of :data
end
```

What I would like to be able to do is to simply add json data to an element, and be able to read and update that data using rails helpers like form_for.

I am trying to avoid having a model for each type of element in the project.  For example I may have a hero object that has various text fields.  Then I may have a carousel object that is comprised of several hero objects.  I also may have a carousel object that is comprised simply of several images.  Is there some way that I can make this happen without creating a model for each element type?

Comment: I'm not completely sure I understand your question, but have you tried adding a "text" column to your model, then parsing that column as json?

Comment: Yes I have a text column and I am serializing the json.  What I would like to be able to do is refer to the keys of the json as methods.  for example:   if I have a element with the data attribute of "foo" => "bar".  I would like to be able to call element.data.foo  => "bar".

Comment: You could build a customized method associated to the model, which receives as parameter foo, searches for it, returns either nil or bar.

Comment: Right but the whole point is that I want a way to do it without actually knowing what those attributes will be.  If i were to pass it in then I would have to know what to pass in.  I the methods dynamically defined similar to active record.

Comment: Right, you could do so by doing "string".to_json.keys, and then iterating through those keys in order to get the values